# AlertDialog and SherlockActivity

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-alertdialog

Im struggling to get a AlertDialog working whilst in an onClick method of a Sherlock activity. Here is my code.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Ooops!!");
builder.setMessage("Sorry.");
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
AlertDialog dialog =builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

Its `new AlertDialog.Builder(this)` where the problem is. `This` is underscored as an error, I also tried `getActivity()` which is common in Sherlock but no luck. Any ideas or direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

By

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityName.this);
```

I guess you use `AlertDialog.Builder(this)` in `onClick` of your activity in which case it does not refer to the activity context. So use `ActivityName.this` where ActivityName is the name of your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

If this code is inside an `Activity`, then use [activity-name].this to reference that `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ActionBarSherlock, you will most likely always use "getSherlockActivity()" in place of "getActivity()"

We use ABS in almost all of our apps for legacy support. Let me know if it works.

Comment: unfortunately `getSherlockActivity()` did not work. It was underlined in read and would not compile. `<activityName>.this` did work however.